# Changing the limits of a summation

Tags: summation

Sorry about bad englsih
Guys, i have this:

`n             n-1
( Σ  3k²-k) + ( Σ  2k-3k²)
 k=1           k=0`

So, the limits of the first one are: `k=1` and `n` and of the second one are `k=0` and `n-1`. To proced, i have to adjust the limits until both have the same limits (k=0 and n), and thats my problem, i dont know exactaly how to manipulate this limits. It would be correct do something like this?

`n               n
( Σ  3k²-k) -> ( Σ  3k²-k+k)
 k=1            k=0`

In this example i subtract the value of k in the limit and add this value into the summation. Would apreciate your help!

Comment: when replacing $k=1$ with $k=0$ in the limits, replace $k$ with $k+1$ in the summation. Notice both give the same starting values and subsequent values. $\sum_{k=1}^n 3k^2-k = \sum_{k=0}^n 3(k+1)^2-(k+1)$

Comment: So, if i change the k valeu from 3 to 0, it would add k+3 in the summation? and for the n, how dows it works?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Well all you have to do is manipulate the second one:

$$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n-1 }{ (2k-{ 3k }^{ 2 }) }  =\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ (3k^2-k)} = \sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{(3(k+1)^2−(k+1))}$$

Comment: Ok, but i would like to understand what happens when you change each one of the limits. What happens when you change n-1 to n and what happens when you change k=0 to k=1.

Comment: subtract and add what?